# Does anyone knows how to use the slmgr /ipk using PS AppDeployToolkit?

Tags: windows, powershell, window, sccm, activation

Does anyone know how to use the slmgr /ipk using PS AppDeployToolkit?
I am trying to create an application which will automatically install the new product key for Windows 7 computers as part of the ESU (Extended Security Updates) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PSAppDeployment-Toolkit contains the cmdlet `Execute-Process` to run executables with parameters.

"slmgr" is not an executable. It is a VB-script. (slmgr.vbs)
You can run a VB-script using `cscript.exe` and call the slmgr.vbs.

The code could look like this:

```
$Status = Execute-Process -Path cscript.exe -Parameters "$env:windir\System32\slmgr.vbs","/ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx" -PassThru -Verbose
```